# Reshape dataframe by string variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['aaa\nbbb\nccc','ddd\nfff\nggg'], 'b':[1,2]})
df
```

I want to get

```
     a  b
0   aaa 1
1   bbb 1
2   ccc 1
3   ddd 2
4   fff 2
5   ggg 2
```

I understand how to make it in `R` with `library(reshape)` but I cann't fint the analog in `python`

Comment: how did such strings end up in a data-frame in the first place?

Comment: I'm not familiar with R but I don't know any other way to split the strings into separate data items other than python's built-in split function.  Like this for example: `[x.split('\n') for x in data['a']]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df = (df.set_index('b')['a']
        .str.split('\n', expand=True)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .reset_index(name='a')
        .reindex(columns=df.columns))
print (df)
     a  b
0  aaa  1
1  bbb  1
2  ccc  1
3  ddd  2
4  fff  2
5  ggg  2
```

Alternative with `numpy`:

```
s = df['a'].str.split('\n')
df = pd.DataFrame({'b':np.repeat(df['b'].values, s.str.len()),
                   'a':np.concatenate(s)})
print (df)
     a  b
0  aaa  1
1  bbb  1
2  ccc  1
3  ddd  2
4  fff  2
5  ggg  2
```

Comment: `.set_index('b')` ah, that was the ticket. Well done.